# Why doesn't puts() print in a single line?

Tags: ruby

This is a piece of code:

```
def add(a, b) 
  a + b;
end

print "Tell number 1 : "
number1 = gets.to_f

print "and number 2 : "
number2 = gets.to_f

puts "#{number1}+#{number2} = " , add(number1, number2) , "\n"`
```

When I run it, my results are spread over several lines:

```
C:\Users\Filip>ruby ext1.rb
Tell number 1 : 2
and number 2 : 3
3.0+3.0 =
5.0


C:\Users\Filip>
```

Why doesn't `puts()` print in a single line, and how can keep the output on one line?

Comment: I see no reason to close this unless there's an exact duplicate I couldn't find.  It's a real question with a straightforward answer that others are likely to find helpful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

<strike>`gets()` includes the newline.  Replace it with `gets.strip`.</strike> (*Update:* You updated your code, so if you're happy working with floats, this is no longer relevant.)

[puts()](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/IO.html#method-i-puts) adds a newline for each argument that doesn't already end in a newline.  Your code is equivalent to:

```
print "#{number1}+#{number2} = ", "\n",
      add(number1, number2) , "\n",
      "\n"
```

You can replace `puts` with `print`:

```
print "#{number1}+#{number2} = " , add(number1, number2) , "\n"`
```

or better:

```
puts "#{number1}+#{number2} = #{add(number1, number2)}"
```

Answer (score 2):

Because `puts` prints a string followed by a newline. If you do not want newlines, use `print` instead.

Answer (score 2):

Puts adds a newline to the end of the output. Print does not. Try print.

http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/IO.html#method-i-puts

You might also want to replace `gets` with `gets.chomp`.

```
puts "After entering something, you can see the the 'New Line': "
a = gets
print a

puts "After entering something, you can't see the the 'New Line': "
a = gets.chomp
print a
```